# wordpress display the full image

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

working with wordpress, I have created a page you can see  [here](https://www.haagsehof.nl/) please do to the `Schoonmaakwerk is mensenwerk` as you can see it looks like this:
[image]

while the image is this:
[image]

I want to be able to display the full image. here is my code for the image part:

```
    #mainSchoonMaker { 
  background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg); 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

if I add no-repeat the image is gone. I want this image to be able scroll able and goes up and dwon with scrolling of the page, anyone any idea how to do this?

Comment: `if I add no-repeat the image is gone. ` what you mean?

Comment: @vel If I add that the image is replaced with white background. For this part I can not make the image be scrollable and not be what it is. Am I clear of What I want to happen?

Comment: you are add the image to body ?

Comment: yes, like this:   `  #mainSchoonMaker { 
  background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }  `

Comment: seems working fine. what is the issue?

Comment: @vel the image is fixed, and when I scroll dwon I cant see the full size image, I want this to be scroll able with the page rather than just being fixed position, do u know what I mean?

Comment: I didnt get you clearly.

Comment: @vel if you visit it you will how it is, when I change the css, the image is what you see on my question, its like half from top and half from bottom and its not a complete image!

Comment: look, the image is fixed position, that means when I scroll up and down it stays the same. however, I want this image to go up and down when I scroll the page up and down. if I remove "position fixed", then I get an incomplete image like in the picture above, I want this image to be shown fully (full size) and moves up and dwon with the scrolling of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    @media (min-width:767px){
    #pl-4 {
        background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: 100%;
        -moz-background-size: 100%;
        -o-background-size: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
}


@media (max-width:768px){
    #pl-4 {
        background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg) no-repeat center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want like this? little space is there. we will fix later.

Comment: Add for #pl-4 and remove from #mainSchoonMaker

Comment: yes, there are spaces left and right of the image and when U look at that part with mobile the image is missing.

Comment: thanks itworks for pc, but for mobile version there is no image, there anyway to fix that aswell?

Comment: thnaks a lot, can you open this website with chrome? it seems that the design is somehow different there!

Comment: in mobile version?

Comment: it is so swierd: when u open the website with firefox or explorer you get a different result than when opening with chrome. how can I fix that? and In mobile things are very inconsistent !!

Comment: any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#mainSchoonMaker { 
  background: url(https://www.haagsehof.nl/content/uploads/2018/02/20171120_Haagsehof_1300_blackoverlay.jpg); 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: auto;
}
```

Comment: this gives an incomplete image!

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with featured images in your theme?

If so, the issue may actually be in the code for your featured image within your theme. Thumbnail (featured image) size can be determined within the media settings in your WordPress site, but featured image sizes can also be manually specified via functions. Here's the developer documentation for building-in functions like this.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/

The image may end up being the wrong size, because WordPress is giving you a custom size automatically due to either your media settings or a theme-specific function.